# Renaming columns in a Dataframe given that column contains data in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Scenario:** I have a list of dataframes. I am trying to rename the columns and change their order, but the column names do not exactly match, for example: a column might be "iterationlist" or "iteration".

I tried a loop inside a loop to read all the columns and if the name contains what I need, change the name of that column, but I get the error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askdirectory
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import glob

# Get content
mypath = "//DGMS/Desktop/uploaded"
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(mypath, "*.xls*"))
contentdataframes = [pd.read_excel(f).assign(Datanumber=os.path.basename(f).split('.')[0].split('_')[0], ApplyOn='')
     for f in all_files]

#get list of dates and put to dfs

for dfs in contentdataframes:
    dfs.rename(index=str, columns={[col for col in dfs.columns if 'iteration' in col]: "iterationlistfinal"})
```

**Question:** What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for get columns names by substring and then reorder columns by subset with join both lists:

```
contentdataframes = []

for f in all_files:
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    df['Datanumber'] = os.path.basename(f).split('.')[0].split('_')[0]
    df['ApplyOn']= ''
    mask = df.columns.str.contains('iteration')
    c1 = df.columns[mask].tolist()
    c2 = df.columns[~mask].tolist()
    df = df[c1 + c2]
    contentdataframes.append(df)
```

Comment: Would it be possible to delete the columns from (c1 + c2) from the main dataframe?

Comment: Yes, `df` is classic DataFrame and if need all columns without `iteration` columns use `df = df[c2]`

Comment: Ok, thats great. So the [~mask] retrieves all columns that do not have the string?

Comment: Not sure if understand, if columns names are `iteration123`, `aa` and `col2` it return `aa` and `col2` columns only

Comment: Exactly that, thank you. And one last question, is it possible to do it for 2 or more different strings? Example: remove those that have "iteration" and those that have "base"?

Comment: Sure, only need `df.columns.str.contains('iteration|base')`

Comment: `|` is here regex OR

Answer (score 0):

Old, but the solution is simply

```
dfs.rename(index=str, columns={col : "iterationlistfinal" for col in dfs.columns if 'iteration' in col} )
```

You can't pass a list in a dictionary